# How to pass javascript variables to php variables with yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

First: I KNOW this is a duplicate. I am creating this because none of the answers to all the other questions satisfy me. I have a very particular situation where I'm using yii and tryi I can't send it through ajax because the php and javascript are on the same page on the same page.

Basically what I'm asking is if you have a page that uses yii and chart js, and you need to render a page that requires two arguments from the clicked bar, which is represented by `activeBars[0]`:

```
<script>
    canvas.onclick = function(event) {
        var activeBars = getBarsAtEvent(event);
        <?php $controller->functionThatRendersView($arg1 /**(activeBars[0].value*/,$arg2 /**(activeBars[0].label*/); ?>
    }
```

I don't care if it will render automatically, that is another problem. I just need to get those arguments to the php.

Thanks.

Also, if it helps, I am passing those two values to javascript through php for loops:

```
labels: [<?php for ($i=1;$i<=$numberIssues;$i++) {
            echo $i . ",";
        }?>],
```

The problem with grabbing `$i` and putting it into the label argument is that I don't know which bar label is the clicked one, I need javascript to pass the clicked bar values back to php.

Comment: You have a real lack of understanding about how this all works. To put it in simple terms, php creates text, some of the text is javascript, some of it is html, some of it is json encoded. It does not talk to the javascript on a web page. You do not see any php on your pages.

Comment: I KNOW that php operates before javascript, and that you don't see the php. It's just that I can't move on without some way to pass those two variables to the view page.

Comment: Javascript is on the browser, php is on the server you basically want to pass things from the browser to the server without having the browser talk to the server. it is not even about the order they run, is where they run.

Comment: I know this too. That's why the php runs before the js. Allthough, it is impossible to move on with this project without this data!!!

Comment: so make an ajax call.... why would you not want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Explain to us again why you can't use ajax. You say "because the php and javascript are on the same page". That's not what ajax is - you need a different URL for the ajax request, and a separate PHP file or something to handle it.

Without ajax it's impossible for javascript to send information to PHP, because the PHP runs on the server *before* the javascript runs on the client. Unless of course you want to do a complete page refresh, which is slower and generally worse from the user perspective.

Comment: Because I tried to use it and it didn't work. If you have better ajax code, or just something that works, I'm open. Also, you can link a web page to help me learn about ajax because I'm sort of new.

Comment: You could start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX , or http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ if you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question! I'm just doing this for anyone else who is stumbling:

To pass javasctipt variable `var jsInteger = 5;` to php you type (in javascript):

```
window.location.href = "yourPhpFile.php?phpInteger="+jsInteger;
```

You access the variable in php like so:

```
$phpInteger = $_GET['phpInteger'];
```

This will require a page refresh, and will redirect you to the php file.